# Python eval error suppression

Tags: python, eval

First off, I'm aware of eval's disadvantages and it will be used in an experiment I want to make only.

I'm creating a script that works just like a Brute-Force algorithm but it won't break passwords but find the solution to a special form of an equation (more details are unnecessary).

There will be lots of strings filled with (often syntactically incorrect) terms like *1+2)+3*

- Is the only way to get the results of these terms via `eval`?
- How to make python ignore syntactical errors occurring in `eval`? (The program shouldn't terminate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To suppress [`SyntaxError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SyntaxError):

```
try:
    eval("1 + 2) + 3")
except SyntaxError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks very pythonic :D

Answer (score 4):

use literal_eval from ast instead and catch ValueError and SyntaxError

```
from ast import literal_eval
try:
    a = literal_eval('1+2)+3')
except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

There are more exceptions possible than SyntaxError only:

- ZeroDivisionError, e.g. for `"1/0"`
- NameError, e.g. for `"franz/3"` (with undefined `franz`)
- TypeError, e.g. for `"[2, 4]/2"`

and even more. So, you may want to catch them all:

```
try:
    eval (expr)

except (SyntaxError, NameError, TypeError, ZeroDivisionError):
    pass
```

Actually, virtually *all* existing exceptions can be thrown and any havoc can be wreaked by the evaluation of any code unless you fence out functions (e.g. `os.system ("rm -rf /")`, see also [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)).

Comment: If you use mappings, KeyError is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

Eval usually raises SyntaxError, you can cover your code with

```
try:
  a = eval('1+2)+3')
except SyntaxError:
  pass
```

Remember, you can isolate `eval` from accessing any functions passing `{ '__builtin__': None }` as second parameter.

Comment: You cannot protect eval against accessing functions: [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)